# MYSQL Insert using Dropdowns and Session Variables

Tags: php, mysql, html, session, insert

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours and can't seem to make headway. I am creating a booking form and it involves 2 dropdown menus and the use of some session variables.

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>" method="POST">
    <input type="date" data-role="date" name = "Date"data-inline="true" id ="Date" placeholder="Click here to select a date">

   <br>
    <select id="Time" name="Time">
        <option value="Null">Select a Time</option>
        <option value="9am">09:00</option>
        <option value="9.20am">09:20</option>
        <option value="9.40am">09:40</option>
        <option value="10am">10:00</option>
        <option value="10.20am">10:20</option>
        <option value="10:40am">10:40</option>
        <option value="11am">11:00</option>
        <option value="11:20am">11:20</option>
        <option value="11:40am">11:40</option>
        <option value="12am">12:00</option>
    </select>
  <br>
    <select id="Person" name="Person">
        <option value="Person1">Who Would you Like to See?</option>
        <option value="Person2">A Doctor</option>
        <option value="Person3">A Nurse</option>  
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" data-role="button" id="submit" value="Book" data-icon="action" data-iconpos="right">
```

I'm not been giving an error message, nor am I getting the success message that I've coded in if the query is successful. Any help would be appreciated

**PHP**

```
//This adds the connection file which has the details to connect to the database and what database to connect to
include_once('connection.php');
//Checks if the submit button is not set
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
exit;
}
    //Declared Variables
    $Date = $_GET['Date'];
            $Time = $_GET['Time'];
            $Person = $_GET['Person'];
    $userID= $_SESSION['user'];
    $GPID= $_SESSION['GPID'];


    //Database Connection, this connects to the database using the connection.php
    $conn=ConnectionFactory::connect();

    //Insert Query
    $query="INSERT INTO `Appointments`(`AppID`, `Date`, `Time`, `Booked_With`, `UserID`, `GPID`) VALUES (NULL, :Date,:Time,:Person,:userID,:GPID)";

    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);

    //Binding values
    //$stmt->bindValue(':post', $Post);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Date', $Date);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Time', $Time);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Person', $Person);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
    $stmt->bindValue(':GPID', $GPID);

    $affected_rows = $stmt->execute();

    //Message if insert is Successful
    if($affected_rows==1){
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
        print "alert('Post Successful')"; 
        print "</script>";
        exit;
        }

    //Terminates the connection
            $conn=NULL;
?>
     </form>
```

Comment: is there `session_start()` anywhere in your code? You need that in order to access the session variables on a page. Also, do you have PHP error reporting turned on for your application ?

Comment: this is playing a big role `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))` and nothing will execute because of it, as is your method.

Comment: Your form method is POST but your PHP code is trying to access variables via $_GET.

Comment: *"I'm not been giving an error message"* that's because you're not checking for them.

Comment: at least have an `else` on your affected rows test, to indicate something went wrong. e.g. `if ($affected_rows == 1) { echo 'ok' } else { echo 'something dun gone blowed up'; }`

Comment: The comment by @Maximus2012 is where you should start other then that you should be checking to make sure that each of your fields has been filled out.

Comment: In a development environment you should modify your php.ini to show you warnings and non fatal errors.

Comment: you're going to get or should get an undefined index notice. you're not checking for errors. [comment #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751281/mysql-insert-using-dropdowns-and-session-variables#comment47634661_29751281) being totally ignored.

Comment: Yes there is a session_start() otherwise i wouldn't be attempting to insert session variables

Comment: @AlexHerrett consult my answer if you haven't yet. I've explained a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code and I'll start from the top.

This conditional statement:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
exit;
}
```

You don't have an element bearing the `submit` name attribute, therefore your script will exit as soon as the page is loaded.

You're probably relying on the "id" for your submit button being:

```
<input type="submit" data-role="button" id="submit" ...
```

and should be named.

I.e.:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" data-role="button" id="submit" ...
```

- Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have signaled an "Undefined index submit..." right away.

Then you're using a POST method in your form, but using GET arrays, where they should be POSTs.

```
$Date = $_GET['Date'];
```

to

```
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
```

- Then, change those to `$_POST` for the rest of your GET arrays.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Plus, make sure you are indeed connecting with PDO and not another MySQL API that doesn't intermix with your PDO query.

Another thing; make sure you've started the session since you are using a session array.

`session_start();` must reside inside all pages using sessions.

Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

- You may also want to use `bindParam` instead of `bindValue` if that still doesn't make it kick in.

Comment: Managed to sort it with a few of your pointers, thank you for the help